# Intermittent failures accessing clustered remote EJB via Spring

Tags: spring, ejb, weblogic, cluster-computing

I have a Spring application which uses a remote stateless EJB hosted in WebLogic.

```
<jee:remote-slsb id="itemService"
    jndi-name="org.example.ItemService"
    business-interface="org.example.ItemService"
    cache-home="false" lookup-home-on-startup="false"
    home-interface="org.example.ItemServiceHome"
    resource-ref="false" refresh-home-on-connect-failure="true">
    <jee:environment>
        java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
        java.naming.provider.url=t3://server1:7101,server2:7101
    </jee:environment>
</jee:remote-slsb>
```

My app gets items from the server thus:

```
ItemEntry[] itemEntries = itemService.listAvailableItems(criteria);
for(ItemEntry entry: itemEntries) {
    Item item = itemService.getItemAccessObject(entry.getKey());
    // Do something with item
}
```

This works fine most of the time.

However, when the item is very new (put in the database in the last couple of seconds), I get intermittent failures when I try to do anything with the Item:

```
java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: CORBA OBJECT_NOT_EXIST 1330446337 No; nested exception is: 
       org.omg.CORBA.OBJECT_NOT_EXIST:   vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1  completed: No
```

For new objects, as described, the failures seem to happen approximately 50% of attempts, and within the for() loop there will be a mixture of failures and successes.

If I change the t3:// address to contain only one hostname:port, the problem goes away.

So, my working theory is that the listAvailableItems() call goes to one server in the cluster -- where the items in question have arrived, and that the failing getItemAccessObject() calls are going to a different server, where the items are still syncing.

If I bypass Spring and manage the EJB context myself, I can't reproduce the problem.

Questions:

1. Is my working theory realistic? (note that the server cluster is a black box to me)
2. How does the Spring SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyBean and/or the WebLogic client divide calls between cluster members?
3. Is there a way to make a sequence of calls go to the same cluster member?

Comment: Please tag more carefully. How is this related to [tag:cluster-analysis]? Retagged to [tag:cluster-computing] instead.

Comment: Oops. I was sure I just tagged it "cluster"

Comment: "cluster" and "clustering" are ambigue, and the latter at least is set up as a synonym for cluster-analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, based on empirical evidence.

If you connect to Weblogic using `wlclient.jar`, it uses the IIOP implementation in the core Java RTE.

If you connect to Weblogic using `wlfullclient.jar`, it uses WebLogic's proprietary T3 protocol.

The IIOP implementation round-robins between servers.

The T3 implemetation seems to maintain a session with a single server, at least while it can.